# How to pass params into spec with airborne gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, airborne

I try to write specs for api with gem `airborne`

How can i pass params into test?

The documentation says:

*For requests that require Query params you can pass a params hash into headers.*

`post 'http://example.com/api/v1/my_api', { }, { 'params' => {'param_key' => 'param_value' } *`

But when i try to run simple test with params like this:

```rb
    it 'returns correctly status filtered tickets' do
      get 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users', { }, { 'params' => {'param_key' => 'param_value' } }
      expect_status(200)
    end
```

i get error:

```
ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1)`
```

Comment: be careful because de documentation example is with POST  method, look the Query Parameters, Request Body and Headers here https://chunksofco.de/testing-your-rails-apis-with-airborne-f5689848f4a5 maybe can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed
`get 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users', { }, { 'params' => {'param_key' => 'param_value' } }`
to
 `get 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users', params => {'param_key' => 'param_value' } }` and it works.